# Can I use granulated sugar instead of demerara sugar

Tags: baking, substitutions, sugar

I need demerera sugar for the outside layer of my shortbread cookies. I have none. Will regular granulated sugar work? Will it burn?

Note: not actually my question, was posted as a [now-deleted answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/42492/1672) to another question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work just fine, but it won't have the same color or the slightly molasses flavor of demerarra.  It also has a finer crystal size, usually, so the texture will be a little less distinctive.

The closest substitute for this purpose, if you happen to have it, is sanding sugar--but I imagine that not everyone keeps that on hand.  It has a large crystal size, and so presents a nice crunchy topping on muffins or shortbread or similar.